How to use Get Records and Decision Element in a Flow
This is my first time using the Get Records element in a Salesforce flow. This is probably very easy, but my approach is not working. I am trying to build a record triggered Flow that:

Starts when a Case is created and the ContactID is a specific Contact Record
Looks for other Cases related to the triggering Contact record, with the same Subject, and the same Created Date
Closes the triggering Case Record if other records with the same criteria in #2 exist.

My approach is to:

Start the Flow when the Cast Contact ID = 003TO00000GObWuYAL


Add a Get Records element to get Case Records that to match the criteria wanted (All Records)


Use a Use a Decision element to determine if records from the previous Get Records element exist


Close the case that triggered the Flow if the other applicable records exist



ISSUE: The flow automatically closes all Cases. The first one created the same day should be Open, and the following Closed.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much for looking.

Hey @NoviceAdmin80, there are a couple of ways to do this.


If you don't expect a high influx of case creations/related cases, you would create an 'Update Record' action with the 4th option selected( to ignore the trigger case using its Id) within a loop that iterates using the Other Cases List you queried in the beginning.


The other option would be to follow best practices, where you would do essentially do the same thing but, rather add them to a collection and then update list outside the loop at the end.


Try the above stuff out, I can help out if you still find it diffcult.

Just to clarify, does it automatically close a Case when it is the first one being created? If so, it's likely due to issues with using Null as the decision node. When using collections, I normally assign a Number variable with the number of records in the collection, using the 'Equals Count' operator.

Actually, re-looking at your configuration, I suspect the real issue here is that you aren't excluding the triggering record from your Get Records node. Make sure you add a criteria of Case.ID Is Not Equal To Triggering Record.Id. As it stands your Get Records will be returning the triggering record even if it is the only one, and then directing the Flow down the path to mark that as closed. In essence, because it's based on a record being created, you will always take the decision path that ends up closing the Case.

Hi @CallumMacErlich. Thank you for the response. I tried adding the condition Id <> Record.CaseID to the Get Records element. I also added an assignment to create a variable for the count of Cases. I then updated the Decision element to trigger if the count of  Cases from the Get Records element is unequal to 0. Instead of closing all but the first case, they are all staying in the New status.

Hi @CallumMacErlich. Disregard my last message. I figured it out. Meh issue was that I needed to get the date value for Create Date because it is a date/time. That was my issue. Thanks again!
